# Identify Container Memory (MEM) consumption (what uses all the memory?)

Tags: linux, bash, docker, kubernetes

I got a container (`registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal`) which runs a bash script (move files) in indefinitely loop
This test is with 900 files every minute and each file is ~ 1 KB (just a small XML)

here part of the yml file including the cmd executed by the pod

```yaml
        command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "shopt -s nullglob && while true ; do for f in $vfsourcefolder/*.xml ; do randomNum=$(shuf -i $FolderStartNumber-$FolderEndNumber -n 1) ; mkdir -p $vfsourcefolder/$vfsubfolderprefix$randomNum ; mv $f $_ ; done ; done"]
        livenessProbe:
          exec:
            command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "test $checkFiles -gt $(ls -f $vfsourcefolder | wc -l)"]
          initialDelaySeconds: 15
          periodSeconds: 15
          timeoutSeconds: 3
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: 256Mi
            cpu: 25m
          limits:
            memory: 4Gi
            cpu: 2
```

after running for ~3days it consumes 3 GB of memory (according to kubectl top)

```
tilo@myserver:/$ kubectl top pod fs-probe-spreader1-0
NAME                   CPU(cores)   MEMORY(bytes)
fs-probe-spreader1-0   217m         3207Mi
```

but I can't find out what takes all the memory.

The **slabinfo** shows lots of object in `cifs_inode_cache`  and `cifs_inode_cache`

here stats from the pod

- ps aux
- top -b
- df -TPh
- cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.usage_in_bytes
- cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.stat
- cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.kmem.slabinfo

```
[root@fs-probe-spreader1-0 /]# ps aux
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root           1  6.5  0.0  13148  3136 ?        Ds   Jan18 279:58 /bin/sh -c shopt -s nullglob && while true ; do for f in $vfsourcefolder/*.xml ; do randomNum=$(shuf -i $FolderStar
root     1266813  0.0  0.0  19352  3764 pts/0    Ss   23:12   0:00 bash
root     1372717  0.0  0.0 1092036 9720 ?        Rsl  23:45   0:00 /usr/bin/runc init
root     1372719  0.0  0.0  51860  3676 pts/0    R+   23:45   0:00 ps aux


[root@fs-probe-spreader1-0 /]# top -b
top - 23:53:56 up 4 days,  2:52,  0 users,  load average: 2.46, 2.31, 2.26
Tasks:   3 total,   1 running,   2 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  5.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 95.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  16009.0 total,    507.8 free,   6127.2 used,   9374.0 buff/cache
MiB Swap:      0.0 total,      0.0 free,      0.0 used.   9551.1 avail Mem

    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
      1 root      20   0   13148   3136   2544 D   6.7   0.0 280:56.60 sh
1398222 root      20   0   19352   3716   3148 S   0.0   0.0   0:00.01 bash
1401883 root      20   0   56192   4208   3660 R   0.0   0.0   0:00.00 top


[root@fs-probe-spreader1-0 /]# df -TPh
Filesystem                              Type     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
overlay                                 overlay   97G   23G   75G  24% /
tmpfs                                   tmpfs     64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs                                   tmpfs    7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
//myshare1.file.core.windows.net/mainfs cifs     100G   28G   73G  28% /trex/root
/dev/sda1                               ext4      97G   23G   75G  24% /etc/hosts
shm                                     tmpfs     64M     0   64M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                   tmpfs    4.0G   12K  4.0G   1% /run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
tmpfs                                   tmpfs    7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs                                   tmpfs    7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /proc/scsi
tmpfs                                   tmpfs    7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/firmware


[root@fs-probe-spreader1-0 /]# cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.usage_in_bytes
3374436352


[root@fs-probe-spreader1-0 /]# cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.stat
cache 19505152
rss 1482752
rss_huge 0
shmem 0
mapped_file 0
dirty 135168
writeback 0
pgpgin 989469294
pgpgout 989464142
pgfault 2149218225
pgmajfault 0
inactive_anon 0
active_anon 1368064
inactive_file 6352896
active_file 13246464
unevictable 0
hierarchical_memory_limit 4294967296
total_cache 19505152
total_rss 1482752
total_rss_huge 0
total_shmem 0
total_mapped_file 0
total_dirty 135168
total_writeback 0
total_pgpgin 989469294
total_pgpgout 989464142
total_pgfault 2149218225
total_pgmajfault 0
total_inactive_anon 0
total_active_anon 1368064
total_inactive_file 6352896
total_active_file 13246464
total_unevictable 0


[root@fs-probe-spreader1-0 /]# cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.kmem.slabinfo
slabinfo - version: 2.1
# name            <active_objs> <num_objs> <objsize> <objperslab> <pagesperslab> : tunables <limit> <batchcount> <sharedfactor> : slabdata <active_slabs> <num_slabs> <sharedavail>
kmalloc-rcl-128       64     64    128   32    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      2      2      0
TCP                   42     42   2240   14    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      3      3      0
kmalloc-rcl-64       320    320     64   64    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      5      5      0
kmalloc-rcl-96       126    126     96   42    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      3      3      0
radix_tree_node      252    252    584   28    4 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      9      9      0
UDPv6                 96     96   1344   24    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      4      4      0
kmalloc-96           168    168     96   42    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      4      4      0
kmalloc-2k            64     64   2048   16    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      4      4      0
cifs_inode_cache  3454395 3454395    776   21    4 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata 164495 164495      0
kmalloc-8           2048   2048      8  512    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      4      4      0
buffer_head         5460   5460    104   39    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata    140    140      0
ext4_inode_cache     290    290   1096   29    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     10     10      0
shmem_inode_cache     66     66    720   22    4 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      3      3      0
ovl_inode            736    736    688   23    4 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     32     32      0
pde_opener           408    408     40  102    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      4      4      0
eventpoll_pwq        224    224     72   56    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      4      4      0
kmalloc-1k            64     64   1024   16    4 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      4      4      0
kmalloc-32           512    512     32  128    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      4      4      0
kmalloc-4k            32     32   4096    8    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      4      4      0
kmalloc-512           64     64    512   16    2 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      4      4      0
skbuff_head_cache     64     64    256   16    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      4      4      0
kmalloc-192           84     84    192   21    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      4      4      0
inode_cache          104    104    608   26    4 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      4      4      0
pid                  128    128    128   32    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      4      4      0
anon_vma            2028   2028    104   39    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     52     52      0
vm_area_struct       837    912    208   19    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     48     48      0
mm_struct            120    120   1088   30    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      4      4      0
signal_cache         112    112   1152   28    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      4      4      0
sighand_cache         60     60   2112   15    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      4      4      0
anon_vma_chain      1957   2368     64   64    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     37     37      0
files_cache           92     92    704   23    4 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      4      4      0
task_delay_info      204    204     80   51    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      4      4      0
kmalloc-64          3264   3264     64   64    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     51     51      0
cred_jar            1323   1323    192   21    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     63     63      0
task_struct           33     52   7680    4    8 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     13     13      0
PING                  64     64   1024   16    4 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      4      4      0
sock_inode_cache      76     76    832   19    4 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata      4      4      0
proc_inode_cache     432    432    680   24    4 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     18     18      0
dentry            3346497 3346497    192   21    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata 159357 159357      0
filp                 576    576    256   16    1 : tunables    0    0    0 : slabdata     36     36      0
```

edit: maybe related:
https://unconj.ca/blog/dotnet-rsync-page-cache-a-kubernetes-war-story.html
and https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/43916
this AKS runs on cgroup V1 (AKS 1.24)

Comment: How large are those files? Is the container consuming the memory constantly, or does it "spike"? Have you tried to reduce the memory limit of the container? According to [this messages on `linux.kernel.narkive.com`](https://linux.kernel.narkive.com/p1YXPFaf/cifs-large-write-performance-improvements-to-samba), it might be that cifs only returns memory under memory pressure.

Comment: 1 KB file, 900 a minute,  I have not tried to reduce the max memory. I will do this Thanks.

Comment: @Tilo Is your issue resolved or are you still facing some errors..? could you please let us know..

Comment: @KranthiveerDontineni I didn't get any error but the question remained. What is taken all the memory on my pod?

Comment: @Tilo did you tried compressing the files and then copying them, I faced the same issue on a linux machine. We used to take dumps of mongodb everyday and then push them to a S3 bucket one day the dump size increased and the script is executed for long duration than it usually take so the memory utilization increased continuously and the machine was down. We checked a few indexes and reduced the size of data and logs, compressed them and copied to the bucket then the memory utilization came back to normal. Running your backup script that frequently might also be a reason, try to limit the rate.

Comment: @KranthiveerDontineni added info about file size to my question.   All great suggestion but how can I identify what is using the memory?

Comment: @Tilo you can debug this by stopping this script and by running the top command for sometime. can you also tell us is there any other service running on this pod